# QGIS dzetsaka plug-in for satellite image classification error how to do?

Tags: qgis, image-classification, sar

When I used dzetsaka plug-in of QGIS to process the SAR image of Gaofen No. 3 satellite, I wanted to use Gaussian mixture model and random forest for classification according to the different attributes (0,1) of the sample point markers I selected. However, it always failed to classify correctly.

It could only classify the part with pixel value and the part without data value. When I used Random Forest, it showed that my raster data and my layer projection were different, but they were the same. What is the reason for this? Can it be solved?

I can't tell if this plugin isn't perfect enough, because I can categorize it correctly using other people's examples. At the end, I managed to classify random forest on ENVI, but now there seems to be no other way to classify Gaussian mixture except QGIS dzetsaka and write code.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of QGIS are you using?

I faced the same issue when I used QGIS 3.24.x but then I backtracked to QGIS 3.16.4 and it worked perfectly. Try using it.

So I believe it is the problem on the recent
versions of QGIS but I do not know specifically what it is.